# Swift - Error propagation while maintaining api clarity

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

With the addition of `ErrorType` to Swift, it's now possible to express error and failure events in a cleaner, more concise manner. We're no longer bound as iOS developers to the old way of `NSError`, clunky and hard to use.

`ErrorType` is great for a few reasons:

- Generic parameters in functions
- Any enum can conform to and implement it
- Works better with the catch/throw paradigm

There are however some problems and one problem in particular that I've been running into lately and I'm curious to see how others solve this.

Say for example, you're build a social networking application akin to Facebook and you have `Group` model. When the user first loads your application you want to do two/three things:

1. Fetch the relevant groups from your server.
2. Fetch the already persisted groups on disk (Realm, CoreData, etc)
3. Update the local copy with the remote copy just fetched.

Throughout this process, you can break the types of errors up into two distinct categories: `PersistenceError` and `NetworkError` where the `ErrorType` conforming enums might look like

```
enum PersistenceError: ErrorType {
    case CreateFailed([String: AnyObject)
    case FetchFailed(NSPredicate?)
}

enum NetworkError: ErrorType {
    case GetFailed(AnyObject.Type) // where AnyObject is your Group model class
}
```

There are several ways/design patterns you can use for delivering errors. The most common of course is try/catch.

```
func someFunc() throws {
    throw .GetFailed(Group.self)
}
```

Here, because functions that throw can't yet specify what type of error they're throwing, although I suspect that will change, you can easily throw a `NetworkError` or a `PersistenceError`.

The trouble comes in when using a more generic or functional approach, such as ReactiveCocoa or Result.

```
func fetchGroupsFromRemote() -> SignalProducer<[Group], NetworkError> {
   // fetching code here
}

func fetchGroupsFromLocal() -> SignalProducer<[Group], PersistenceError> {
    // fetch from local
}
```

Then wrapping the two calls:

```
func fetch() -> SignalProducer<Group, ???> {
   let remoteProducer = self.fetchGroupsFromRemote()
   .flatMap(.Concat) ) { self.saveGroupsToLocal($0) // returns SignalProducer<[Group], PersistenceError> }
   let localProducer = self.fetchGroupsFromLocal()
   return SignalProducer(values: [localProducer, remoteProducer]).flatten(.Merge)
}
```

What error type goes in the spot marked `???`? Is it `NetworkError` or `PersistenceError`? You can't use `ErrorType` because it can't be used as a concrete type and if you try using it as a generic constraint, `<E: ErrorType>`, the compiler will still complain saying it expects an argument list of type `E`.

So the issue becomes, less so with try/catch and more so with functional approaches, how to maintain an error hierarchy structure so that error information can be preserved throughout different `ErrorType` conformances while still having that descriptive error api.

The best I can come up with so far is:

```
enum Error: ErrorType {
    // Network Errors
    case .GetFailed

   // Persistence Errors
   case .FetchFailed

   // More error types
}
```

which is essentially one long error enum so that any and all errors are of the same type and even the deepest error can be propagated up the chain.

How do other people deal with this? I enjoy the benefits of having one universal error enum but the readability and api clarify suffer. I'd much rather have each function describe what specific error cluster they return rather than have each return `Error` but again, I don't see how to do that without losing error information along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Just trying a solution to your problem, may not be a perfect one. Using protocol to easily pass around the error objects :

```
//1.
protocol Error {
  func errorDescription()
}

//2.
enum PersistenceError: ErrorType, Error {
  case CreateFailed([String: AnyObject)
  case FetchFailed(NSPredicate?)

  func errorDescription() {

  }
}

//3.
enum NetworkError: ErrorType, Error {
  case GetFailed(AnyObject.Type) // where AnyObject is your Group model class
  func errorDescription() {

  }
}

//5.
func fetch() -> SignalProducer<Group, Error> {
  ...
}
```

Comment: That certainly is a good solution. Unfortunately it still suffers from the same problem, that any function or method that returns an error type will always be of type `Error`.

Comment: Right, but even though the type is Error which is actually a subclass object with baseclass pointer. And you can get dynamic behaviour based on the subclass type implementation of the protocol method. May be I'm not getting the context exactly but you can also improve the behaviour by adding an extension method to the ErrorType and use that seamlessly with any of the custom subclass types.